# BigQuery scripting: running a SQL query based on each row included in a table column

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

My origin table includes **url_id** and **SQL** [standard sql, string]

[image]

I would like to run each of the SQL statements in the string column "SQL" and join the outcome with the correspondent url_id

expected outcome

[image]

**UPDATE**

to make this easy to reproduce I´ve imported a similar schema from public BQ:

> bigquery-public-data.covid19_italy.data_by_province

[image]

if I run

```
select string_agg(
    format('select %i as url_id, (%s) as simpleSKU', url_id, sql), 
    ' union all '   )

FROM `xxx.staging.test_query
```

it returns
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
execute immediate (
  select 'select url_id, region_name from (' || string_agg(
    format('select %i as url_id, array(%s) as region_names', url_id, sql), 
    ' union all '
  ) || '), unnest(region_names) as region_name'
  from your_table
);
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output it

[image]

Comment: hi
it returns me
Query error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element at [1:1]

I have also updated the question to make it more debuggable

Comment: i think i tested this and it worked as expected. will check one more time shortly. stay tuned :o)

Comment: see update in my answer. looks like when i initially tested - i used oversimplified dummy data returning only one row per url_id thus the error for real life data - it is fixed now

Comment: thank you, do you know if that´s possible to create a table or save somehow the execute immediate?